# Unit test in xcode : inconsistent build result

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
Test Case '-[TestParse testParsing]' started.
/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 415:  3256 Segmentation fault  "${THIN_TEST_RIG}" "${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}" "${TEST_BUNDLE_PATH}"
/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:451: error: Test rig '/Developer/Platforms /iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest'    
exited abnormally with code 139 (it may have crashed).
```

I got this seg fault message while I built test case randomly (sometime it built successfully, sometimes it throws seg fault). I'm not sure how I could fix this error.
Only thing I test here is I wrote one class name Parse with class level method. And in test case I just call it like

```
var = [Parse methodName:filepath];
```

method is like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempBox = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
FILE *fd = fopen([filePath UTF8String], "r");
if(!fd){
    NSLog(@"fail to open file\n");
}
char buf[4096], *ptr;
char name[512], description[4096];
int  isNewInfo = 2, description_continue = 0;

//  for (line = 0; line < [args objectAtIndex:1]; line++) {
//      fgets(buf, 4096, fd);
//  }

while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fd) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(buf, "\n") == 0){
        isNewInfo -= 1;
        if(isNewInfo == 0){
            isNewInfo = 2;
            description_continue = 0;
            description[strlen(description)-1] = '\0';
            [self saveDrinkandResetBuf:name
                    detail:description box:tempBox];
            if(name[0] != 0 || description[0] != 0){
                NSLog(@"fail to reset..."); 
            }

        }
    }
    if(description_continue){
        strcat(description, buf);
        continue;
    }
    if((ptr = strstr(buf, "Drink Name: "))){
        memcpy(name, buf+12, strlen(buf));
        name[strlen(name)] = '\0';
        continue;
    }
    if((ptr = strstr(buf, "Description: "))){
        memcpy(description, buf+13, strlen(buf));
        description_continue = 1;
        continue;
    }
}
fclose(fd);
NSLog(@"finish parsing section\n");
//[tempBox release];
return tempBox;
```

Not sure what is going on here..

Comment: post the `methodName:` code please.

Comment: At the moment it looks like you're leaking tempBox when returning it

Comment: im still quite confused about release (im still not very familiar with Obj-c). I thought release is like free in c, so I tend to release memory whoever call this method..

Comment: apparently description[strlen(description)-1] = '\0'; caused this error but not sure why. Its just set null terminator at the end of char array to remove new line. When I removed -1, it works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, the problem is in array management.

In C if the array is declared in a function (and is not declared as a global or static one), then value of its elements is undefined. So your `char description[4096]` is filled with any values. And nobody said that '\0' will be there.

And the result of `strlen(...)` for non-null-terminated char string is not defined. It *may* result in a memory access violation, as it will keep counting until it reaches the first memory byte whose value is 0.

Moreover, when you call `description[strlen(description)-1]`, `strlen` can return 0 (imagine that the first value, stored there initially was '\0' and your file was started with two empty lines [to reach this line of code]) - so array index will be -1...

Comment: good catch!! I was kinda doubting about strlen in other point.